# How to restart Windows 8 directly to Startup Settings menu?

Tags: windows-8, boot, drivers, shutdown, code-signing

I need to restart Windows 8 with no driver signature check mode.

I use `shutdown -o -r` command, then I need click **Troubleshoot**, then **Advanced Options**, then **Windows Startup Setting**, then **Restart** and finally press **F7 Disable driver signature enforcement** on **Startup Settings** menu.

Can I restart Windows 8 directly to **Startup Settings** menu without described clicking on menus?

Comment: I suppose you could create a boot option and make that the default one.  One must ask...Why are you booting with unsigned drivers?

Comment: Because I need to install driver that have no signature and Windows 8 allow this only after reboot to special mode.
I'm searching how to minimise clicks to do that.